# Returning response when user is unauthorised in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

When a user is not authenticated, Laravel redirects all request made to routes using `auth::api` middleware to the default laravel login page. However since I am building the API only, I want to return a `401 unauthorised` response to any app that will be consuming my api. This should be simple but for some reason, I haven't been able to do just that. Here's what my code looks like

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    if ($user->id == auth()->user()->id) {

        // do something here
    } else {

         return response()->json([ 'status_message' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
     }
}

public function update(Request $request, User  $user)
{
    if ($user->id == auth()->user()->id) {

        // do something here
    } else {

        return response()->json(['status_message' => 'Unathorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

When I hit the endpoints calling these methods and the user isn't authenticated, I am redirected to the default laravel login page. How can I override this default behavior?

Comment: use `Auth::check()` . if authenticated it will return true and false when not authenticate ....

Comment: I think you should remove `Auth Middleware` apply to that route first.

Comment: @hs-dev2MR tried that and I still get redirected to the login page

Comment: How you tried , show me .

Comment: @hs-dev2MR here's how  `if (Auth::check()) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: response()->json must be return json data only ! May be are you missing your route ?

Comment: Route is fine and as you can see I am returning json data in my else statement.

Comment: Did you use middleware like `auth,guest` in your route or controller ! That will redirect to login page as default if not authenticated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197142/discussion-between-mena-and-hs-dev2-mr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved guys. Here's how I did it, in the `Handle.php` file in `app\Exceptions\` I added this code to the render function

```
if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
    return response()->json(['status_message' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
}
```

And that was it.

Note: this worked in laravel 5.8

Answer (score 1):

Call api.auth middleware in your routes as follows

```
  $api->group(['middleware' => 'api.auth'], function ($api){
     //your routes  
  });
```

Create a file Authenticate.php inside Middleware folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;
class Authenticate {
    /**
     * The authentication guard factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

}

and in kernel.php which is inside http folder include the following

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
   ];
```

Comment: Ok there is progress but not there yet. Following your code I get the message `"message":"Not found"` which means something is still not right. In the `Authenticate.php` file that ships with Laravel 5.8, there is a `redirectTo($request)` function that should help I think. This is the code inside that function `if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }` How can we work around it to achieve my goal.

Comment: In .env file have u included the following
`API_PREFIX=api`

Comment: No. I did not add that to the .env file